# Tuning parameters of PDEs given a set of data

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, st.statistics, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I am interested in doing statistical inference in the context of PDEs. Loosely speaking, the kind of problem I have in mine is the following.

**Problem setting**

Let $(t_i, x_i, y_i) \in  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ be some given *observations*, for $i = 1, \dots, N$. We assume that $x_i \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\Omega$ is a nice domain.
Assume that we know that the data come from a model
\begin{equation}
y = f_\lambda(t, x) + \varepsilon,
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon$ is some random error, $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) \in \mathbb{R}$ are parameters and $f_\lambda \colon \mathbb{R} \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a solution to a PDE of the kind
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f = \mathcal{F}\left(t, x, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f, \dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} f, \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} f, \dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n^2} f, \lambda\right)
$$
satisfying Dirichlet or Neumann conditions on $\partial \Omega$.

**Goal**
Find $\widehat{\lambda}$ that $f_{\widehat{\lambda}}$ fit the data best (f.e. it minimzes the sum of squared errors).

---

**Is there any literature available about such problems?** Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: The type of problems you describe is generally called "parameter identification" and is a special case of the general field of **inverse problems**. There is a huge literature that you can find just by searching those terms. The form of your $\mathcal{F}$ suggests to me that you are looking at the case when the PDE is parabolic. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-1704-0_1 and references therein may be useful to you.

Comment: Hi @WillieWong ! Thank you very much! You are right. I am mostly interested in the parabolic case.